# bind Win_L with 'd' in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind, hotkeys

```
from tkinter import *

def quit_1(event):
    print("you pressed Win_L")
    root.quit()
def quit_2(event):
    print("you pressed Win_L+D")
    root.quit()

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Win_L>', quit_1)     #working
root.bind('<Win_L-D>', quit_2)   #not working
root.mainloop()
```

How I bind Win_L + D event to a funcction

commenting line
root.bind('Win_L-D',quit_2) runs the program

Comment: If you are on Windows, many of the "Windows key" shortcuts are already usurped by the operating system and cannot be reassigned.

Comment: windows key alone 'Win_L' working fine which is used to open taskbar it triggers quit_1 function on click . I tried <'Control-slash'> and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind the Win_L + D key combination to the quit_2 function, you need to modify the event string in the bind method. Instead of using `'<Win_L-D>'`, you need to use `'<Win_L>d'`:

```
root.bind('<Win_L>', quit_1)
root.bind('<Win_L>d', quit_2)
```

This is because Win_L is a modifier key and cannot be used in combination with other keys. When you press Win_L + D, the Windows operating system generates a new key code for the combination. In Tkinter, this code is represented by d (the d key), so you need to use it in the event string.
With this change, pressing the Win_L + D key combination will print "you pressed Win_L+D" to the console and quit the root window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution It works but it needs to hit both keys at the same time its functionality is not similar to '<Control-slash>' or any other key bindings , anyways thanks for your solution

Comment: Try to use `root.bind_all("<Control-slash>", your_function)`